# Javascript cookies not working on android app built with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

Hi I have an android app built with PhoneGap. I am using Java Script cookies. It works fine on Android 2.3, but when I am using it on Android 4.0 it is not working.

The code is given below

I have set cookies

```
document.cookie = "first_name=abc" ;
document.cookie = "last_name=xyz" ;
```

and find the cookies syntax is that

```
  var cookies = {};

        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var split = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                var name_value = split[i].split("=");
                name_value[0] = name_value[0].replace(/^ /, '');
                cookies[decodeURIComponent(name_value[0])] =     decodeURIComponent(name_value[1]);
            }

            var FirstName= cookies["first_name"];
            var LastName = cookies["last_name"];
        }
```

Comment: Could you show code examples? And why do you say it's not working?

Comment: what do you mean by not working? are you not able to read the cookie?